# Можно ли отсортировать ArrayList?

Tags: java, сортировка, arraylist

Имеется `ArrayList` вида `String : int`. Как отсортировать его по возрастанию/убыванию по "колонке" `int` ?

вот примерный вид коллекции

```
ArrayList <Data> data;
data.add(new Data("машина", 10));
data.add(new Data("мотоцикл", 15));
data.add(new Data("велосипед", 2));
```

сам класс дата

```
public class Data
{
    String value_1;
    String value_2;

    Data (String value_1, String value_2)
    {
        this.value_1 = value_1;
        this.value_2 = value_2;
    }

    public String getValue1()
    {
        return value_1;
    }

    public String getValue2()
    {
        return value_2;
    }
}
```

Собственно хочу отсортировать по числам получившуюся коллекцию и получить что то вроде этого :

```
велосипед, 2
машина, 10
мотоцикл, 15
```

Comment: каким образом в коллекции хранятся эти значения, pojo-объекты или что? что за колонка в коллекции может быть? привидите код, как заполняется колекция

Comment: В `ArrayList` нет "колонок", он хранит список обьектов. Как их сортировать, зависит от самого обьекта. Без уточнения понятия "колонка" в вашем конкретном случае, ответить невозможно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
data.sort(Comparator.comparing(Data::getValue2));
```

Comment: Только в классе `Data` очевидно, ошибочно, `value_2` объявлено как `String`, а нужно наверное `int`...

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець сортировка по полю произойдёт в любом случае. Если автору вопроса нужно сортировать не в алфавитном порядке, то он может или изменить тип поля или добавить приведение типов.

Comment: Да, только приведенный автором код не скомпилируется 